# Create dataframe using some columns of other dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Name" = c("John", "Dora"))
y <- data.frame("AA" = c(11,19), "Re" = 11:12)
```

I would like to create a third dataframe whose columns are `SN` and `Name` from `x`, and `AA` from `y`. But with

```
df=cbind(x$SN,x$Name,y$AA)
```

I obtain a wrong result.

Comment: `cbind` will create a matrix, why not `data.frame(x$SN,x$Name,y$AA)` ?

Comment: @markus thank you! I fixed the problem by using `cbind.data.frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `select` and `bind_cols` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  select(SN, Age) %>% 
  bind_cols(y %>% 
              select(AA))
#  SN Age AA
#1  1  21 11
#2  2  15 19
```